# How to display all records group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table.

```
id | promoid | fecha       | Tarifa
--------------------------------------
1  |    1    | 2016-10-01  |  74.38
2  |    1    | 2016-10-02  |  74.38
3  |    2    | 2016-10-01  | 111.57
4  |    2    | 2016-10-02  | 111.57
```

I want to group by and show all the record by promoid between dates. I have tried with group by but i only obtain one record (the first).

This is my SQL

```
SELECT * 
  FROM promociones
 WHERE fecha >= '2016-10-01' 
   AND fecha < '2016-10-03' 
 GROUP  
    BY promoid
```

when the sql run it show only first row grouped by promoid. something like this.

```
id | promoid | fecha       | Tarifa
-------------------------------------- 
1  |    1    | 2016-10-01  |  74.38

3  |    2    | 2016-10-01  | 111.57
```

The table is so long, but i want to obtain all the rows realted by promoid. Something like this.

```
id | promoid | fecha       | Tarifa
--------------------------------------
1  |    1    | 2016-10-01  |  74.38
2  |    1    | 2016-10-02  |  74.38
3  |    2    | 2016-10-01  | 111.57
4  |    2    | 2016-10-02  | 111.57
```

Comment: Specify the desired output together with output you obtain with your query

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want to group by'? What would the desired result look like?

Comment: That would be SELECT * FROM promociones ORDER BY id

Answer (score 1):

### "Normally"...

grouping by a query **"allways"** implies two things:

- The resultset has less records than the equivalent counterpart query without `group by`
- Select's expressions list (what is shown in the output) include any grouping function (`sum()`,`count()`,`max()`) related and meaningfull to each group that `group by` generates.

Especificaly to your question: You, expect "all" records (the same amount) and you haven't or expect or propouse any related grouping function. So as was said on comments, seems that it can solved as `select * from ...` or you need to explain or think better what you want.

So given:
`select expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4 group by expr1, expr2`

Please think of `group by` as a prosses that recieves some input data and gives out some output data following this rules:

- Output will have exactly just one record for each diferent combination of expr1, expr2 that exists on the input data.  (this is why your example shows two records)
- expr3, expr4 must be (or contain) grouping functions, which will output "that group" related data.
  A word here about MySql: on MySql syntax, if you omit any grouping function over expr3 and expr4, you can assume that it uses `whatever()` as grouping function, in this way: `whatever(expr3), whatever(expr4)` and it outputs any value from within "that group" (this is why you can use * on your example and you have the shown output)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tabletwo
 WHERE fecha >= '2016-10-01' 
   AND fecha < '2016-10-03' 
ORDER BY promoid
```

Comment: maybe you can provide him with some explanations ?

Comment: maybe i dont explain well. I need to separate in blocks all rows that contain the same promoid

Comment: Show another example